# Exceeded 30 redirects after add `host` to headers[python requests]

Tags: python, python-2.7, http-headers, python-requests

Get a url with `host` in headers would throw exception `Exceeded 30 redirects`.
It so weird that I can't figure out.
Below is the test code:

```
>>> url = 'http://bbs.duchang8.com/forum-29-1.html'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> print r.status_code
200
>>> headers = {
...     'Host': 'bbs.duchang8.com',
... }
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/www/article_fetcher/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/data/www/article_fetcher/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/data/www/article_fetcher/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/data/www/article_fetcher/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 594, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/data/www/article_fetcher/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 114, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Comment: Try the same with urllib2 to see what will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Don't override the `Host:` header.

Or, override it with the host to which the client is redirected.

**Long answer**

By explicitly setting the `Host` header you are telling `requests` to use that header in *all* subsequent requests, including any requests reissued as a result of a redirect response from the server.

In this case the `requests` client is being redirected to location `http://www.duchang8.com/forum-29-1.html` which is hosted by a different server; `www.duchang8.com` vs. `bbs.duchang8.com`. Although both host names resolve to the same IP address, the remote HTTP server treats them differently.

The nett result is that `requests` continues to use the `Host:` header that you supplied in preference to the correct one returned by the server. Then subsequent requests to the new location are rejected (by redirect) due to the mismatch between the URL/server host and the `Host:` header.

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://bbs.duchang8.com/forum-29-1.html'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.history
[<Response [301]>]
>>> r.history[0].headers
{'content-length': '178', 'server': 'nginx', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'location': 'http://www.duchang8.com/forum-29-1.html', 'date': 'Mon, 03 Aug 2015 12:20:31 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html'}
```

Here we see that the client was redirected to `http://www.duchang8.com/forum-29-1.html` by a HTTP 301 response and `location:` header.

Using `curl` you can see what happens if you try to supply a different `Host:` header when getting the new location:

```
$ curl -v -L -H 'Host: bbs.duchang8.com' http://www.duchang8.com/forum-29-1.html
*   Trying 61.160.249.39...
* Connected to www.duchang8.com (61.160.249.39) port 80 (#0)
> GET /forum-29-1.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Accept: */*
> Host: bbs.duchang8.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 03 Aug 2015 12:27:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 178
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.duchang8.com/forum-29-1.html
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host www.duchang8.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://www.duchang8.com/forum-29-1.html'
* Found bundle for host www.duchang8.com: 0x21b54c0
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host www.duchang8.com
* Connected to www.duchang8.com (61.160.249.39) port 80 (#0)
> GET /forum-29-1.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Accept: */*
> Host: bbs.duchang8.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 03 Aug 2015 12:27:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 178
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.duchang8.com/forum-29-1.html
<
# and so so, and so on....
```

It ends up in a redirect loop. The same sequence of requests and responses occurs with `requests`, which will eventually decide is never going to end and abort the request.